# Can 3.2 kernel KVM VMs run in a 2.6 kernel host

Tags: redhat, kvm-virtualization, kernel

So I got a Redhat6.2 and going to install it on a new IBM x3650 m4 server. However I want use Debian because I'm more familier with it. Since x3650 doesn't support Debian(I've tried but no luck), I plan to install Redhat6.2 as the base system and run multiple KVMs with Debian 7 in it.

Question: Redhat6.2 is the 2.6 kernel while Debian7 is kernel 3.2. So is it ok to run a 3.2 kernel vm in a 2.6 kernel host ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, and here's why:

KVM is a so called [full virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_virtualization) hypervisor, hence **it simply doesn't matter what OS and what version** of it you are running inside your VM. Basically, your VM and your Host only share hardware *(ok, the Host fakes some of it to the guest, but you get the general idea)*.

As ALex_hha pointed out, problems would only arise when you're not using a full virtualization hypervisor; like OpenVZ, where higher-level sharing occurs; the kernel versions must be the same on both VM and Host.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine; I've run VMs up to kernel 3.9.x in a KVM virtual machine on an EL6.4 host. Make sure you actually are running the current update of RHEL rather than staying back at a previous service pack.

Answer (score 0):

It should be no problem, will be work. The problems could arise if you use openvz

Answer (score 0):

it works just fine, lots of the RHEL KVM tests involve running fedora guests, where the kernel is even fresher